# SXA Date format not applied to field where fallback used in rendering variant

Tags: sxa

Using `Sitecore 9.1.1` with `SXA 1.8.1`.

I have a rendering variant which outputs a date field in a particular date format.  When my first field being evaluated is empty then the fallback value displays in the selected format.  However if my first field has a value then it displays it in the format "8/29/2019 12:00:00 AM".  The same date format selection was made in both fields.

My rendering variant:
[image]

My template - both are date fields, the only difference being the Published date gets a default of now.
[image]

Reviewed output:

[image]

vs my Published fallback:

[image]

Comment: Double-check if everything is published.

Comment: @DawidRutkowski I did jump into the web database and everything seemed to be there. I was kind of hoping the date format string hadn't been published for an easy explanation :)

Comment: Raising a support ticket as I have reproduced in a vanilla sxa install. Damn was looking forward to using these cool looking fallback fields. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was raised as a bug - Sitecore reference 362491.

The workaround was to have rule based display of the variant fields:
[image]